# How to customize legend in Google Charts with Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

I'm using Chartkick for visualization some statisitcs data in my Ruby-on-Rails project. Chartkick based on [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=ru). Is there some way to customized data output in legend of chart?

For example:

```
= pie_chart User.get_country_statistic, library: {legend: {position: "left"}, chartArea: {left:0, width:'100%'}}
```

It gives
[image]

But I need something like this:
[image]

I.e. more information in legend. How I can get it?

Comment: I have red the SourceCode from this Ruby wrapper and i can't see something like legend options. I think (because the wrapper is really slim) it is not supported.

Comment: @bMalum It's true. But probably there is easy way to fix chartkick

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: you could use a Table chart in place of the legend...